# JAXB how to create repeating elements with different attribute values

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to output the following XML using JAXB:

```
<ScreenData step="1" description="My descriotion">
    <element name="name1" type="type1" value="value1"/>
    <element name="name2" type="type2" value="value2"/>
</ScreenData>
```

To do this I'm using the following code:

```
screenData.getElement().add(element);
        element.setName("name1");
        element.setType("type1");
        element.setValueAttribute("value1");

        screenData.getElement().add(element);
        element.setName("name2");
        element.setType("type2");
        element.setValueAttribute("value2");
```

This is then what is output:

```
<ScreenData step="1" description="My First XML">
                <element name="name2" type="type2" value="value2"/>
                <element name="name2" type="type2" value="value2"/>
            </ScreenData>
```

Comment: You're adding two times the same element. Create two different instances of your `element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are creating separate instances of `Element`.  Currently you appear to be adding the same instance twice.

```
    Element element1 = new Element();
    screenData.getElement().add(element1);
    element1.setName("name1");
    element1.setType("type1");
    element1.setValueAttribute("value1");

    Element element2 = new Element();
    screenData.getElement().add(element2);
    element2.setName("name2");
    element2.setType("type2");
    element2.setValueAttribute("value2");
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: That worked thanks for all your help tonight, hope I haven't been too much of a nuisance

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Set or a List.

```
    List<MyClass> l= new ArrayList<MyClass>();

    myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.setAttr("attr1");

    l.add(myClass);

    myClass2 = new MyClass();
    myClass2.setAttr("attr2");

    l.add(myClass2);
```